# Difference between ~ /pattern/ and ~ "pattern"?

Tags: regex, awk

So, the question is pretty straightforward : In awk, is `if ( var ~ /pattern/ )` the same as `if ( var ~ "pattern" )` ?

I've done some basic test on a csv, and both seems to yield the same result... Is there any subtle difference I've missed ?

Comment: `"string"` will be converted to regexp literal first.. so, you will have a clash for backslash characters.. compare `echo 'a\bc' | awk '$0 ~ "\\b"'` and `echo 'a\bc' | awk '/\\b/'`

Comment: see also: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very well explained in GNU `awk` docs under [3.6 Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps)

> `NOTE`: When using the `~` and `!~` operators, be aware that there is a difference between a regexp constant enclosed in slashes and a string constant enclosed in double quotes. If you are going to use a string constant, you have to understand that the string is, in essence, scanned twice: the first time when `awk` reads your program, and the second time when it goes to match the string on the lefthand side of the operator with the pattern on the right.
>
> What difference does it make if the string is scanned twice? The answer has to do with escape sequences, and particularly with backslashes. To get a backslash into a regular expression inside a string, **`you have to type two backslashes`**.

A simple demonstrative example to explain the difference. When using a regexp constant

```
echo 'foo*bar dude' | awk '$1 ~ /foo\*bar/'
```

and with dynamic regexp string, because the regexp string under `".."` undergoes scanning twice, you need an additional `\` to escape the `\` added for `*`

```
echo 'foo*bar dude' | awk '$1 ~ "foo\\*bar"'
```

All the backslash escape sequence characters undergo this special handling when using dynamic regexps. For e.g. to escape a `\n` in the line

```
echo 'foo\nbar dude' | awk '$1 ~ /foo\\nbar/'
```

and

```
echo 'foo\nbar dude' | awk '$1 ~ "foo\\\\nbar"'
```

The documentation also clearly explains which one to use

> String constants are more complicated to write and more difficult to read. Using regexp constants makes your programs less error-prone. Not understanding the difference between the two kinds of constants is a common source of errors.
>
> It is more efficient to use regexp constants. `awk` can note that you have supplied a regexp and store it internally in a form that makes pattern matching more efficient. When using a string constant, awk must first convert the string into this internal form and then perform the pattern matching.
>
> Using regexp constants is better form; it shows clearly that you intend a regexp match.

Comment: I've searched this information in the chapter 6 and 7 for so long... I'm going to learn how to read a table of content soon :P Thank you !

Comment: Glad that it helped. I always go with keywords like 'GNU awk dynamic regex' and see links that point to the official manual.

Comment: I didn't use the "dynamic" keywords, got pointed to chap6, never get out ^^

Comment: There's still something to be said for buying a book and reading it :-). [Effective AWK  Programming, 4th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do).